# Are object immutable?

Tags: java, object

I have to decide whether the following two objects are immutable. I looked up the definition stating: “An object is considered *immutable* if its state cannot change after it is constructed”.

```
public class Car {
    private int spareTires = 1;
    private String model = "Volkswagen";
    private Person driver = new Person();
    public double engineSize = 2.0;
    public int getSpareTires() { return spareTires; }
    public String getModel() { return model; }
    public Person getDriver() { return driver; }
}

public class Person {
    private String name = "James";
    public void setName(String s) { name = s; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

`Person` isn't immutable since it has a mutator method (`setName()`).

However, I'm not sure about `Car`. `Car` doesn't have any mutator methods but according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html the fields must be declared final and static which isn't the case. Also I believe it's possible to change the state through `public double engineSize = 2.0;`?

Comment: You can mutate public fields of an instance, yes

Comment: And you only need final to set as immutable, not static

Comment: Questions and answers on Stack Exchange follow normal forum-post syntax. There is no need for HTML.

Comment: Your code contains *html* tags, I cannot edit it.

Comment: Joshua Bloch said is not mutable "if visible state of object can be changed". Example: hashcode may be cached in private variable, and not computed until request via getter

Comment: @cricket_007 Fields don't need to be `final` for a object to be immutable.

Comment: "Don't allow subclasses to override methods. The simplest way to do this is to declare the class as final"  There's another reason they're both mutable.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I’m not sure about car. Car doesn’t have any mutator methods
>   but according to
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html
>   the fields must be declared final and static which isn’t the case.

Not necessarily static, final is enough.

> Also I believe it’s possible to change the state through ” public
>   double engineSize = 2.0; ” ?

Indeed, to be immutable, you don't have to expose as public the fields which describe the state of an instance. Otherwise, any client class of the instance may change `engineSize`.

Besides, this getter in  the `Car` class does the Person modifiable since `Person` is not immutable :

```
   public Person getDriver() { return driver; }
```

Comment: Fields don't need to be `final` for a object to be immutable.

Comment: Not strictly indeed but  declaring them as final is a good practice as it limits the modification of the fields by forbidding at least any new assignations.  I mainly answered about what the OP has read in the provided link and in this context the `final` modifier is enough  but the `static` modifier not required. @ Andreas

Comment: True. The `static` part is probably just a "typo" by OP, since linked article says `private`, not `static`.

Answer (score 0):

`Car` is not immutable since it has the `driver` property which is mutable and exposes the public `engineSize` method which is mutable. Also none of both classes is final.